# The union of two transitive binary relations is not necessary to be transitive.

Tags: relations, self-learning

If binary relations T and S are both transitive, then the binary relation $T\cup S$ is also transitive.

———

My proof is as follows

This union is not transitive. So show this by a counter example.

Let T and S be relations on $N=\{1,2,3\}$.

And let us define

$(x,y)\in T $ iff $x<y$

$(x,y)\in S $ iff $x>y$

According to this definition, I construct the sets

$T=\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)\}$

$S=\{(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)\}$

As it is clearly seen, both T and S are transitive.

$T\cup S=\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)\}$

$T\cup S$ is not transitive because (1,2) and (2,1) are in $T\cup S$ but (1,1) is not in $T\cup S$.

—-

Is this counter example true and enough to show this statement?

Also, is there any mistake in notation?

Note: I know there are many examples on this issue. But, I want to do my own example in order to understand better and to remember in the exam :)

Thank you for your great helps!

Comment: this is hard to follow.  First you define the relations $T,S$ via the usual ordering.  Then you define them as finite sets.  Which definition did you mean?

Comment: To expand on what @lulu has said you should make sure to include the set you're defining the relation on, which in this case is $\{1,2,3\}$ rather than say, $\mathbb{Z}$. Note that your proof would hold in either case for the same reason.

Comment: Of course, I am just guessing what you mean by $N$.  Specifically, I am guessing that you meant $\mathbb N$, the natural numbers.  If you meant something else, you ought to specify.

Comment: Yes N is natural number (I am not good at latex) sorry. @lulu

Comment: Yes N is natural number @CyclotomicField

Comment: Can you please write down my example in the most correct way? if it is possible for you? Thanks a lot dear @CyclotomicField

Comment: Can you please write down my example in the most correct way? if it is possible for you? Thank you so much @lulu

Comment: Just cut out one or the other of the two definitions.  Either one will work fine, but you have to pick one and stick with it.

Comment: I see @lulu If I define any set N={1,2,3}, then is this okay? I corrected this in the question post above. (Sorry I am international relation student, so I am not mathematician. These topics are very difficult for me) thank you for your helps.

Comment: No worries.  Yes:  if you define $T,S$ on the finite set $\{1,2,3\}$ then your explicit example works just fine.  The problem arose when you wrote $(x,y)\in T$ iff $x<y$.  On the natural numbers, that would include  $(172,1928)$ to pick a random example.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much :) you’re the best! :) @lulu